# How to draw the different graph in android single layout

Tags: android

I am new to android just now i started to working on android,in my application i need to draw a 3 graph in one layout.I have attached the image exactly which out put i want..please help me to solve this problem

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

to draw graph what you can do is

1) put canvas on layout.

2) devide it on appropriate size.

3) draw on canvas directly.

may be this technique is tedious but its most efficient & easy to understand.